# How can I avoid UIButton title label text clipped?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I try to set string to

```
button.titlelabel.text
```

For example I set `'ISTANBUL'` 
It looks like `'IST...'`

How can I solve this problem. I want to write all charactes like `'ISTANBUL'`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming this is a `UIButton`, you should set the text like this:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"ISTANBUL" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You also need to make sure that your button is large enough to fit the full text.

Comment: instance method forControlState not found..it says

Comment: I don't understand why this works and setting it using dot syntax doesn't? it's the same property right?

Comment: @AdamWaite This is just the way `UIButton` works. The `titleLabel` property is for setting the more advanced `UILabel` properties (such as `textAlignment`, `lineBreakMode` etc.), but you should use the `setX:forState:` methods for basic properties (text, colour, shadowColour).

Answer (score 1):

Make the button wider, or drop the font size.

Comment: If using Interface Builder then simply change the properties. If using code, change the frame to set the size [myButton setFrame:CGFrameMake(*left*, *top*, *width*, *height*)]; and to set the font... [myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]];

Answer (score 1):

Use `- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state` with the state `UIControleStateNormal` to set the title of a `UIButton`

Comment: Can you implement this for a button to me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the size of the text and then adjuste the width of the UIButton

Try this to find the rigth width:

```
- (CGFloat)widthOfString:(NSString *)string withFont:(NSFont *)font {
     NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
     return [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes] size].width;
 }
```

And then adjust the buttons width (button.frame.size.width).